# Using template base class template constructor in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

i know that you can use constructors from a base class in a derived class like

```
class A {
public:
    A() {};
}

class B : public A {
public:
    using A::A;
}
```

Furthermore you can use a constructor from a template base class like

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    A() {};
}

template<typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
public:
    using A<T>::A;
}
```

Suppose that class A now has a template function as constructor:

```
template<typename T1>
class A {
public:
    template<typename T2>
    A() {};
}

template<typename T1>
class B : public A<T1> {
public:
    using A<T1>::A;                           // nope
    using A<T1>::A<>;                         // neither             
    template<typename T2> using A<T1>::A<T2>; // sounds good, doesn't work

}
```

How could you use the base class constructor in the derived class?

Comment: How would you call that constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- `template<typename T2> A() {}` is unusuable as a constructor, since there is no way to deduce `T2`.
- You can only inherit all constructors at once. You can't choose specific ones.

Other than that, `using A<T1>::A;` is correct.

Comment: You're totally right, i've edited the signature of the constructor in the last code snippet so that T2 can be deduced. Well, that's easier than i thought it was. Certainly there was another problem with my more complex code, tested  your answer with this minimal sample and it works well! Thanks :)

Comment: @syntaxerror147 You're welcome! Usually it's discouraged to make significant changes to the question after getting an answer, to avoid confusing future readers. So  I've rolled back the question edit, I hope you don't mind.